# Pandas split column based on category of the elements

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a pandas.DataFrame in it I have a column. The columns contains, integers, strings, time...

I want to create columns (containing [0,1]) that tells if the value in that column is a string or not, a time or not... in an efficient way.

```
          A
0  Hello 
1  Name
2  123
3  456
4  22/03/2019
```

And the output should be

```
          A    A_string A_number A_date
0  Hello       1        0        0
1  Name        1        0        0 
2  123         0        1        0
3  456         0        1        0
4  22/03/2019  0        0        1
```

Comment: try this: `df['type'] = df['A'].apply(type)`. let me know if it works

Comment: This method and then a one hot encoding solves it @Hamid

Answer (score 4):

Using pandas str methods to check for the string type could help:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df['A_string'] = df.A.str.isalpha().astype(int)

df['A_number'] = df.A.str.isdigit().astype(int)

#naive assumption
df['A_Date'] = (~df.A.str.isalnum()).astype(int)

df.filter(['A','A_string','A_number','A_Date'])

    A       A_string    A_number    A_Date
0   Hello       1          0           0
1   Name        1          0           0
2   123         0          1           0
3   456         0          1           0
4   22/03/2019  0          0           1
```

Comment: the problem of this is that I have  to know before hand what are the categories. Except that it seems a good idea

Answer (score 2):

We can use the native pandas `.to_numeric`, `to_datetime` to test for dates & numbers. Then we can use `.loc` for assignment and `fillna` to match your target df.

```
df.loc[~pd.to_datetime(df['A'],errors='coerce').isna(),'A_Date'] = 1

df.loc[~pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce').isna(),'A_Number'] = 1

df.loc[(pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce').isna()) 
       & pd.to_datetime(df['A'],errors='coerce').isna()
       ,'A_String'] = 1

df = df.fillna(0)


print(df)

            A  A_Date  A_Number  A_String
0       Hello     0.0       0.0       1.0
1        Name     0.0       0.0       1.0
2         123     0.0       1.0       0.0
3         456     0.0       1.0       0.0
4  22/03/2019     1.0       0.0       0.0
```